# drop a series of true false in pandas removes first two lines

Tags: python, pandas

Handing the pandas.drop function a list of `True` and `False` statements drops the first two lines. Why? Is this a bug?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2,3]})
df.drop([False, False, True])
   foo
2    3
```

Also only giving it a list of `False` will just drop the first line.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2,3]})
df.drop([False, False, False])
   foo
1    2
2    3
```

Comment: Unless 'gotchas' is the name of some feature or technology, please don't create that tag.

Comment: @Stijn I guess pointing out that gotchas are technically poorly designed features won't help? I don't care too strongly either way. I figured it could be a helpful tag, that's all.

Comment: The question and answer are useful, just the tag isn't. Take a look at the *Avoid meta-tags* section of http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @Stijn Thanks, that was a good read. I hadn't seen this page before tbh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Explanation why this happens

No, this is not a bug, it is just a side-effect of that `True` and `False` are equal to `1` and `0`

This code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2,3]})
df.drop([False, False, True])
```

Is identical to this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2,3]})
df.drop([0, 0, 1])
```

The pandas drop function takes a list of indicies to drop, not a mask.

## How to properly use the drop method

The proper way of using masks to drop data is either to mask, then access the index and hand this to the drop function:

```
df.drop(df[[False, False, True]].index)
   foo
0    1
1    2
```

Or just by inverted masking:

```
df[~pd.Series([False, False, True])]
   foo
0    1
1    2
```